# Image Rotation Horizontally

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I rotate an image horizontally in WP7? It should seem like if we rotating a coin on a table. I am able to rotate in an angle but not able to do it horizontally.

Comment: Do you mean this kind of move? http://tinyurl.com/7fetlyj Do you want it to rotate 360 degrees or less?

Comment: yes, I want the image to rotate 360 degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PlaneProjection` ([See description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection%28v=VS.95%29.aspx))

Set CenterOfRotationX at 0.5 and ([See a good description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection.centerofrotationx%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) and use a Storyboard to animate the RotationY property of the PlaneProjection instance ([enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection.rotationy%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))

If you have Expression Blend installed, I highly suggest you use that to create your Storyboard - it makes life much easier.